# protractor - facebook login with window handle switch - tests run before login completes

Tags: angularjs, facebook, authentication, protractor, window-handles

I am attempting to write simple styling tests on an angular page using Protractor, and the page I am testing can only be properly viewed after completed a Facebook login.
Problem appears to be that the tests continue to run while the attempt to log in is still actively happening, and so tests fail because the log in has not actually happened yet and the styles have not properly loaded.
Cannot (under current understanding) use an `onPrepare()`, because this functionality does not occur in the majority of test pages.
Tried using `beforeAll()`, and even putting the functionality into it's own `'it'`, same issue occurs.
Problem is not with switching windows.
Current state-

```
 it('...', function() {

    facebookbutton.click();
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

        facebookemail.sendKeys('user');
        facebookpass.sendKeys('pass');
        facebooklogin.click();

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
    });
});

describe('Styling Tests --', function() { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Write subsequent test logic in a callback function after clicking facebook login button. it will work.

```
  Code Snippet:
   it('...', function() {

      facebookbutton.click();
      browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){

      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

      facebookemail.sendKeys('user');
      facebookpass.sendKeys('pass');
      /*use callback function after clicking login button*/
      facebooklogin.click().then(function(){
           browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
           browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
       });
    });
   });
```